# Not able to upload file. Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Here's my code:

html:

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" method="POST" action="/badmin/register" enctype="multipart/formdata" files="true">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>
</form>
```

backend:

```
public function register(Request $request){
    $request['image']; /// getting file name here when i return it.

    return $file = Input::file('image'); ///getting nothing.
}
```

But when I am trying to hit it using postman, I am getting a correct response.

Comment: Try: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: You're trying to return the assignment. Assign the variable, then return it, if that's what you're trying to do. Or just return the Input, but if your function is only returning the Input:: call, then that seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: @aynber You are right. Technically, it possible to assign a variable and compare it directly, but in this case it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `enctype` of your form is missing a dash.

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" method="POST" action="/badmin/register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

That's why only the name if the file is sent to the server and not the file.

Also to test the value of a variable in Laravel it's better to use [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd), this will return the type and the value of any variable at any location. Like so:

```
dd($request->file('image'));
```